# Model reference adaptive controller

Tags: control-system, pid-controller, controller, model, algorithm

I have designed a model reference adaptive controller for which I have obtained the step response for different values of adaptation gain. I have attached the output graph obtained. Can anyone please tell me why there is a gap between the model output and the actual output of the system[image: model reference adaptive controller]

Comment: The gap is likely due to your output being a sampled system and the delay is one sample.

Comment: Please insert a magnified image also showing the gap. Also please add more details about the order of the system and the adaptive controller. Perhaps the input signal (step) isn't persistently exciting ?